# Can someone explain how this finds the max number?

Tags: javascript

```
var myArray = [1, 12, 3, 5, 6];
var maxValue = null;
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (maxValue === null || maxValue < myArray[i]) {
        maxValue = myArray[i];
    }
}
// shows 12
```

I see that it loops through `myArray` and checks if `maxValue` is equal to null (which it is?) OR if `maxValue` is less than current array element (which it also is?) and then assigns `maxValue` to the current array element in for loop. How does this find the largest number? Seems so simple but I don't see how it's finding largest integer ...

Comment: Add a `console.log(maxValue);` inside your `for` loop to see how it works.

Comment: it checks the last max value against the actual value. at start it checks the `null` value and assigns ththe actual value without further check.

Comment: Why does it return 12 though? I don't see any console.log or anything like that

Comment: Your console is evaluating the last value of `maxValue` implicitly. The code doesn't return anything. Try just typing `myArray` after your code has executed.

Comment: are you sure there isn't more code? its impossible for it to print 12 here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach is to use the first value directly and iterate from the second index, without using placeholder like `null` (which requires to check this value in every iteration) or `-Infinity` for a really small value.

```js
var array = [1, 12, 3, 5, 6],
    max = array[0],
    i;

for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (max < array[i]) {
        max = array[i];
    }
}

console.log(max);
```

Comment: I like this idea, nice! Thank you. By "placeholder" you refer to `null` right?

Comment: right, please see above (maybe you need to refresh the page ...).

Answer (score 0):

Let us iterate over the problem. We have set the maxValue variable as null. In the first iteration, the maxValue will hold the value of myArray[0] which is 1. It will compare 1 with myArray[1] in next iteration. Since myArray[1] is larger than maxValue, maxValue will get the value of 12. Now all the other components are smaller than maxValue and maxValue is not null anymore. Thus the value of maxValue at end of the iteration will be 12.

Comment: Thank you this helps, is there any significance to setting maxValue to null versus 0?

Comment: Yes! You will get a wrong answer had your array been of only negative numbers.

Comment: the `typeof` result is different from `0` and `null`

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the initial value with 0 and removing the null test makes it easier to read. Adding a console.log lets you trace the execution of the loop.

```js
var myArray = [1, 12, 3, 5, 6];
var maxValue = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    console.log( i, myArray[i], maxValue );
    if (maxValue < myArray[i]) {
        maxValue = myArray[i];
    }
}
// shows 12
```